# Java: Gson parse without square brackets

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a JSON file that I'm trying to parse that doesn't have surrounding square brackets: `[...]`.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/schwartzadev/c9ef1f1079f506c0022fd4725e583382) is the Java code. (This has the Gson dependency in Maven) I keep on getting the error on line 29, "This is not a JSON Array." However, when I add square brackets to the beginning and end of the JSON file, it parses just fine. How can I parse this without the brackets.

Here is the JSON:

```
{
  "title": "Title",
  "content": "whatever",
  "author": "Yuki Noguchi",
  "date_published": "2017-02-15T20:25:00.000Z",
  "lead_image_url": "https://media.npr.org/assets/img/2017/02/15/ap_17039860769171_wide-d1a5d3c17f00d78fd1df9d19a96e1d7b3bd38e60.jpg?s=1400",
  "dek": null,
  "next_page_url": null,
  "url": "http://www.npr.org/2017/02/15/515425370/trump-labor-pick-andrew-puzders-nomination-appears-in-jeopardy",
  "domain": "www.npr.org",
  "excerpt": "The fast-food CEO faced fierce opposition from labor groups, plus personal controversies. Ultimately, he didn't have support from enough Republican senators.",
  "word_count": 751,
  "direction": "ltr",
  "total_pages": 1,
  "rendered_pages": 1
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Parse it into a `JsonObject` instead of an array.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: on line 29 you are trying to get an array even though you doesn't have an array. Instead of trying to get an array get JsonObject as others have mentioned

Answer (score -1):

Try this one, append "[" open and "]" close braces and store in temporary variable and pass that temporary variable to parse.

for example,

```
var jsonVar = { name:"hello", title: "WOrld" };
var tmpJsonVar = "[" + jsonVar + "]";
var jsonObject =  JSON.parse(tmpJsonVar);
```